# How to read a binary file of complex numbers in C++

Tags: c++, matlab

I have a 320Mb binary file (data.dat), containing 32e7 lines of hex numbers:

```
1312cf60 d9 ff e0 ff 05 00 f0 ff 22 00 2f 00 fe ff 33 00 |........"./...3.|
1312cf70 00 00 00 00 f4 ff 1d 00 3d 00 6d 00 53 00 db ff |........=.m.S...|
1312cf80 b7 ff b0 ff 1e 00 0c 00 67 00 d1 ff be ff f8 ff |........g.......|
1312cf90 0b 00 6b 00 38 00 f3 ff cf ff cb ff e4 ff 4b 00 |..k.8.........K.|
....
```

Original numbers were:

```
(16,-144)
(-80,-64)
(-80,16)
(16,48)
(96,95)
(111,-32)
(64,-96)
(64,-16)
(31,-48)
(-96,-48)
(-32,79)
(16,48)
(-80,80)
(-48,128)
...
```

I have a matlab code which can read them as real numbers and convert them to complex numbers:

```
nsamps = (256*1024);
for i = 1:305
     nstart = 1 + (i - 1) * nsamps ;
     fid = fopen('data.dat');
     fseek(fid,4 * nstart ,'bof');
     y = fread(fid,[2,nsamps],'short');
     fclose(fid);
     x = complex(y(1,:),y(2,:));
```

I am using C++ and trying to get data as a `vector<complex<float>>`:

```
std::ifstream in('data.dat', std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
fseek(infile1, 4*nstart, SEEK_SET);
vector<complex<float> > sx;
in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&sx), sizeof(int));
```

and very confuse to get complex data using C++. Can anyone give me a help?

Comment: @Sergey thank you for your information, but I would like to learn the way to use C++ to read and process data. my expectation is to have a vector complex (f[i] = complex<float>(sx[i].real(), sx[i].imag()). After that, I can apply fast fourier transform (fft) to calculate the spectrum of the signal.

Comment: Sergey: i am sorry, that is the data.dat file, I forgot to rename it. I know I am still wrong with the data type. The data.dat file was written from : outfile.write((const char*)&buff.front(), nwrite * sizeof(complex<short>)); outfile.flush(); outfile.close()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Theory

I'll try to explain some points using the issues in your code as examples.

Let's start from the end of the code. You try to read a number, which is stored as a four-byte single-precision [floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), but you use `sizeof(int)` as a size argument. While on modern x86 platforms with modern compilers `sizeof(int)` tends to be equal to `sizeof(float)`, it's not guaranteed. `sizeof(int)` is compiler dependent, so please use `sizeof(float)` instead.

In the matlab code you read `2*nsamps` numbers, while in C++ code only four bytes (one number) is being read. Something like `sizeof(float) * 2 * nsamps` would be closer to matlab code.

Next, `std::complex` is a complicated class, which (in general) may have any implementation-defined internal representation. But luckily, [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) we read that

> For any object `z` of type `complex<T>`, `reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[0]`
>   is the real part of `z` and `reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[1]` is the
>   imaginary part of `z`.
>
> For any pointer to an element of an array of `complex<T>` named `p` and
>   any valid array index `i`, `reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)[2*i]` is the real part
>   of the complex number `p[i]`, and `reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)[2*i + 1]` is
>   the imaginary part of the complex number `p[i]`.

so we can just cast an `std::complex` to char type and read binary data there. But `std::vector` is a class template with it's implementation-defined internal representation as well! It means, that we can't just `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&sx)` and write binary data to the pointer, as it points to the beginning of the vector *object*, which is unlikely to be the beginning of the vector *data*. Modern C++ way to get the beginning of the data is to call `sx.data()`. Pre-C++11 way is to take an address of the first element: `&sx[0]`. Overwriting the object from the beginning will result in segfault almost always.

OK, now we have the beginning of the data buffer which is able to receive binary representation of complex numbers. But when you declared `vector<complex<float> > sx;`, it got zero size, and as you are not [pushing](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) or [emplacing](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) it's elements, the vector will not "know" that it should resize. Segfault again. So just call `resize`:

```
sx.resize(number_of_complex_numbers_to_store);
```

or use an appropriate constructor:

```
vector<complex<float> > sx(number_of_complex_numbers_to_store);
```

Before writing data to the vector. Note that these methods operate with "high-level" concept of number of stored elements, not number of bytes to store.

Putting it all together, the last two lines of your code should look like:

```
vector<complex<float> > sx(nsamps);
in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(sx.data()), 2 * nsamps * sizeof(float));
```

### Minimal example

If you continue having troubles, try a simpler sandbox code first.

For example, let's write six `float`s to a binary file:

```
std::ofstream ofs("file.dat", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
float foo[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(foo), 6*sizeof(float));
ofs.close();
```

then read them to a vector of complex:

```
std::ifstream ifs("file.dat", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
std::vector<std::complex<float>> v(3);
ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(v.data()), 6*sizeof(float));
ifs.close();
```

and, finally, print them:

```
std::cout << v[0] << " " << v[1] << " " << v[2] << std::endl;
```

The program prints:

```
(1,2) (3,4) (5,6)
```

so this approach works fine.

### Binary files

Here is the remark about binary files which I initially posted as a comment.

Binary files haven't got the concept of "lines". The number of "lines" in binary file completely depends on the size of the window you are viewing it in. Think of binary files as of a magnetic tape, where each discrete position of the head is able to read only one byte. Interpretation of those bytes is up to you.

If everything should work fine, but you get weird numbers, check the displacement in `fseek` call. A mistake by a number of bytes yields random-looking values instead of the floats you wish to get.

Surely, you might just read a vector (or an array) of `float`s, observing the above considerations, and then convert them to complex numbers in a loop. Also, it's a good way to debug your `fseek` call to make sure that you start reading from the right place.

Comment: Sergey: Again thank you very much for your detail lecture, now I completely understand how the binary data look like. Thank you very very much.....

Comment: I have is vector complex with only zero, I know I did wrong data type, I hope you can explain to me again , here is my code:   double total_bytes, vector_size; streampos begin,end;
std::ifstream ifs("channel_1.dat", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in); begin= ifs.tellg(); ifs.seekg (0, ios::end); end= ifs.tellg();
total_bytes = end - begin;  
vector_size= total_bytes/ sizeof(complex<short>);    
std::vector<std::complex<float> > v(vector_size);
ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(v.data()), vector_size*sizeof(complex<short>));  but I still get only zero, Can you help? thank you so much.

Comment: Sergey: i am sorry, that is the data.dat file, I forgot to rename it.

Comment: @longkhong OK, I found your other question. Will try to help soon.